# How to trigger an event in an iOS app from a UNNotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My app has an UNNotificationServiceExtension object that exists in a separate project, which handles the receipt and processing of notifications.

I'd like to be able to trigger an event in the main app under certain circumstances, whether the app is active or not. Is this possible? If so, what mechanism would I use to achieve this?

If not, I'm worried that I'll have to use the main app to poll a shared data source when it's activated and respond to the data it reads.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. after a bit of googling I found this:

[Using URL Schemes to Communicate with Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

This will allow me to communicate between apps.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days for that, which will be in 3 hours.